# how to handle burst of streaming data for a very short duration

Tags: streaming, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, data-processing

we want to develop a system that can handle bursts of streaming data, 1M events/sec for 1 minute duration and then the load would reduce significantly to 100/sec.

These 1 min data bursts can happen 5-10 times a day and we need to aggregate(simple grouping) the data and dump to another service. These aggregations need to happen every 200ms.

What would be the best arch to follow here with min costs and max throughput? I have looked at google pubsub/p + google dataflow + apache beam but that seems like would take a lot of time to auto scale.

Any suggestions to explore further are welcome

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can use Pub/Sub together with Dataflow. This Dataflow pipeline could contain following steps:

1. reads messages from a Pub/Sub topic,
2. parses the JSON of the input message and produces one main output
3. and optionally writes into BigQuery.

When data  will create millions of messages per second in the Pub/Sub topic,  Dataflow scales the number of workers to process the backlog of incoming Pub/Sub messages and keep the system lag of the pipeline at optimal levels.

I would recommend to check following [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb104-dataflow-streaming-pipeline/#0), which shows how to start a Dataflow pipeline, monitor it, and, lastly, optimize it together with Pub/Sub.